# Start a tile server on Android app

Tags: leaflet, android, offline

We want to have a offline Leaflet map on mobile. For this we want to use some kind of Android app which will serve as a tile provider when offline. The Leaflet will refer to this Android app as tile layer provider e.g. as

```
L.tileLayer('androidappservice/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                {    maxZoom: 16  }).addTo(mymap);
```

Do you know if there is such Android app?

Comment: You don't need any special app/service, you can read tiles as local files, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962292/leaflet-rendering-tiles-from-devices-local-storage

Comment: @TomazicM This is a web app hence we can't read local files. We want web app to refer to android app for tiles only, when offline.

Comment: That's one funny combination :) I would rather recommend asking at android.stackexchange.com, as this seems more like asking how to run a local server on Android. I am pretty sure the answer will frustrate you.

Comment: If tiles are part of your app's assets you should be able to read them.